# Autocompletion in DataGrip not working for a particular table

Tags: database, postgresql, datagrip

I am using DataGrip as my IDE for my Postgres Database. However for a specific table the autocompletion seems to not work at all.
This is even correct when I tried pgAdmin.

Do you possible have an idea on the origin of the problem.
PS: The table does belong to same user as all the other tables. In the image below is the result of a query on pg_tables where the table in first line does not have the issue whereas the table in the second line is the one with the problem.

[Screenshot of pg_tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37JXc.png)

[Screeshot of failing autocompletion on the table for the primary key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBgXQ.png)

Comment: A screenshot with not working completion would be useful here. Also, is there the table in the database tree?

Comment: Yes the table appears in the table tree. And you can find the screenshot of an autocompletion failing attempt in the second image link in the edit of the post.

Comment: But you have these columns right? The screenshot of the whole screen will help. And even better to create a ticket here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE